# How to do I get files I deleted locally but didn't commit the changes?

Tags: perforce

I have deleted some files/folders in my local machine but I did not commit the changes to repository.

How to get the deleted files back?

I am not getting the deleted files after performing the `p4 sync -f`. Why I am not getting the deleted files after the force sync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't reverted the changes Perforce will still think you want to delete those files so won't restore them.

You need to go to the pending changelist and do a "revert" on those files to get them back.

Use the "p4 revert" command:

```
p4 revert -c default //...
```

This "revert[s] every file open in the default changelist to its pre-opened state."

[Source](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/revert.html)

If you don't want to revert all the files, move the files you want to revert to a separate changelist and use the "-c" option.

If you only have a few files to revert you can specify the name of the file:

```
p4 revert lib/libopenssl.a include/openssl.h
```

for example, reverts exactly those two files (thanks to Bryan).

Comment: Or just say the names of the specific files you want to revert: `p4 revert lib/libopenssl.a include/openssl.h`, for example, reverts exactly those two files.

Comment: But there is no way to retrieve the file with the recent edits once the file is deleted, right?

Comment: @SilentMonk not unless you've taken a backup. If you took a development branch and checked into that at frequent intervals then you might have the version you need.